# where do I enter my password after launching pgadmin4

Tags: database, postgresql, passwords, new-operator, pgadmin

entering password in pgadmin4

I launched my pgadmin4 with a view to enter password and load database but cannot see where to enter password and load the database. This is to help me as postgres user who is about to analyze data from database. I do not see where to enter my passwrod

Comment: Create a new server connection.

Comment: this question seems to belong to https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=pgadmin+login

Answer (score 0):

[image: PGADMIN4 Picture]
You need to right click on server and register a server. Then click on the Connections Tab and enter the password/username etc.